# ExecutorService awaitTermination method vs using CountDownLatch

Tags: java, multithreading

So I'm still a bit new to multithreading and came across these two classes. What I understood is that an `ExecutorService` can be a thread pool and via the `awaitTermination` method the thread in which it is called comes to a halt until the threads in the thread pool have finished running.

Then there is the `CountDownLatch` you can give to your `Runnable`s. These can then in turn call the `countDown()` method. If you then use the `await()` method in your main thread, this thread will come to a halt until the countdown has reached zero.

I don't seem to spot the difference in result between the two ways? Why would I ever use a `CountdownLatch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of different things where you might want to wait for lots of things to be processed that don't involve shutting down your thread pool.

For example you might have 5 servers that you are monitoring, with a thread to monitor each one. A Countdown Latch is used to fire off another thread once all the first 5 have connected.

It can also be used in many other situations, for example if you have some initialization to happen then all the threads may wait on the countdown latch until all the initialization has finished and the latch is counted down to zero.